# HTML5 video tag, javascript to detect playing status?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, chromium

Can you use javascript to detect if the video is playing? paused? or stopped?

I know VLC under browsers can do this, but don't know how to do it without VLC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if HTML5 Video element is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599076/detect-if-html5-video-element-is-playing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can query the `media` object to get the playback state:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#playing-the-media-resource

> "A media element is said to be potentially playing when its paused
>   attribute is false, the element has not ended playback, playback has
>   not stopped due to errors, the element either has no current media
>   controller or has a current media controller but is not blocked on its
>   media controller, and the element is not a blocked media element."

Comment: awesome, I will give it a go now.