# How to tell if a <video> element is currently playing?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I see that the [MediaElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#htmlmediaelement) interface exposes attributes like `paused`, `seeking`, and `ended`. Missing from the list, however, is `playing`.

I know there are [`playing` events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-media-playing) that fire when an element *starts* playing, and [`timeupdate` events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-media-timeupdate) events periodically while playing, but I'm looking for a way to determine whether a video is playing *right now*. Is there an easy way to determine this?

The closest I've got is:

```
!(video.paused || video.ended || video.seeking || video.readyState < video.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA)
```

Answer (score 150):

There is not a specific attribute that will reveal whether a `MediaElement` is currently playing. However, you can deduce this from the state of the other attributes. If:

- `currentTime` is greater than zero, and
- `paused` is false, and
- `ended` is false

then the element is currently playing.

You may also need to check `readyState` to see if the media stopped due to errors. Maybe something like that:

```
const isVideoPlaying = video => !!(video.currentTime > 0 && !video.paused && !video.ended && video.readyState > 2);
```

Comment: This assumption does not seem to hold in IE. While the user is seeking (and the video is thus not playing right now), currentTime can be greater than 0 and paused = ended = false at the same time.

Comment: currentTime gives me the video duration in seconds as a float in Safari if video has not started playing yet.

Comment: Its sad such a property isn't built to the spec!!

Comment: @QCaron I don't see your point, you can compare a float against zero also?

Comment: @OZZIE I guess there is/was an issue with Safari. If the video has not started yet, `currentTime` might give you the video duration instead of the real current time (which should be 0 if the video has not started yet).

Answer (score 128):

It has been a long time but here is a great tip. You can define `.playing` as a custom property for all media elements and access it when needed. Here is how:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
    get: function(){
        return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
})
```

Now you can use it on `<video>` or `<audio>` elements like this:

```
if(document.querySelector('video').playing){ // checks if element is playing right now
    // Do anything you want to
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
var video = $('selector').children('video');

var videoElement = video.get(0);

if (!videoElement.paused) {}
```

One way of doing it using Jquery

Answer (score 3):

See my response here: [HTML5 video tag, javascript to detect playing status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647168/html5-video-tag-javascript-to-detect-playing-status/6647216#6647216)

Basicaly, as said before there is no single property to check but according to the spec it's a combination of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. Solution is very simple and straight forward:

```
// if video status is changed to "ended", then change control button to "Play Again"
video.onended = function() {
    $("#play_control_button").text("Play Again");
};

// if video status is changed to "paused", then change control button to "Continue Play"
video.onpause = function() {
    $("#play_control_button").text("Continue Play");
};

// if video status is changed to "playing", then change control button to "Stop"
video.onplaying = function() {
    $("#play_control_button").text("Stop");
};
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation of these properties?

Comment: @brasofilo I think the below link will provide enough information for controlling video with JavaScript:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onplaying = function() {
alert("The video is now playing");};
```

you can use this [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_playing.asp)

Answer (score 1):

you could check for the readyState if its equal or greater than HAVE_FUTURE_DATA and paused is false. This could confirm that video is playing.

As its explained in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ playing event will be fired when:
"readyState is newly equal to or greater than HAVE_FUTURE_DATA and paused is false, or paused is newly false and readyState is equal to or greater than HAVE_FUTURE_DATA"