# Referencing recorded video to see if it is playing or not (JS)

Tags: javascript, blob, recordrtc

So I am using [Muaz Khans RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/RecordRTC-to-PHP/index.html) to record Video and Audio for a website. I have been trying to write a script to see if the recorded video is being played or not. The problem I'm having is how to reference the video that has been created.

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
function vidplay() {
    var video = document.getElementById("videoURL");
    if (video.paused) {

        //DESIRED ACTION 

    } else {

        //DESIRED ACTION
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877403/how-to-tell-if-a-video-element-is-currently-playing

Comment: Show your html including dynamic

Comment: It's sadly not a duplicate as my question is somewhat more complicated as a blob object is created and I'm having trouble referencing it rather than just a generic video tag.

The HTML is exactly the same as the HTML used for the demo.

Comment: Are you creating `<video>` tag dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ddxadv3y/

> Simply check for `video.currentTime`. It must update.
>
> Otherwise consider `video` is **paused** or **ended**.

```
<h1></h1>
<video controls muted style="width:20%;"></video>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        if(lastTime) return;
        checkForTimeChange();
    };

    var lastTime;
    function checkForTimeChange() {
        if(!lastTime) {
            lastTime = video.currentTime;
        }

        if(lastTime == video.currentTime) {
            h1.innerHTML = 'paused';
        }
        else {
            h1.innerHTML = 'playing';
        }

        lastTime = video.currentTime;

        setTimeout(checkForTimeChange, 500);
    }
</script>

<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function() {});
</script>
```