# HTML Dom audio is playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

```
var myMusic = document.getElementById("music");
function play() {
myMusic.play();
}
play()
```

I tried like this but i can't find how can i control it

If the audio is playing don't go the play function

Is anybody knows it?

Thank you...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a <video> element is currently playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877403/how-to-tell-if-a-video-element-is-currently-playing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 check if audio is playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing)