# application should not be idle while playing video in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

user should logout if he is inactive for 5min. for that i added some events those are

```
fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
  fromEvent(document, 'click'),
  fromEvent(document, 'mousedown'),
  fromEvent(document, 'keypress'),
  fromEvent(document, 'DOMMouseScroll'),
  fromEvent(document, 'mousewheel'),
  fromEvent(document, 'touchmove'),
  fromEvent(document, 'MSPointerMove'),
  fromEvent(window, 'mousemove'),
  fromEvent(window, 'resize'),
```

whenever above events are triggered then the timer resets again but i don't know what event i need to add for video playing. while playing the video it should not be inactive. it is working fine for all the above events.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6877530/21409916) sounds like it could help you!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can provide the way you embed/show/activate the video.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I'm using videogular/ngx-videogular library to play videos and it is playing in modal popup.

Comment: it is fixed now. i used video timeupdate event to capture video progress. Thanks everyone for your response.

`formEvent(document.getElementById("Video"),'timeupdate')`