# How can I change the hover cursor when a video is playing or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a web project that requires me to change the cursor to a custom image when hovering over an object. This is the code I have used:

```
.add-to-wishlist:hover {
  cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,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'), auto;
}
```

I now want to be able to extend that to detect the state of the object and show a different image depending on that state.

The key example is when hovering over a video player, show one image if the video is playing and show another image if it is not. These would be an image that says 'pause' or 'play' respectively.

I am just not sure how to do this, with pure CSS or including JavaScript. How do I detect if a video is playing and change the hover cursor image accordingly?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of video? Maybe player adds some class, so you can do `.add-to-whishlist.playing:hover` and `.add-to-whishlist:hover`

Comment: They'd likely be embeds from YouTube or Vimeo, or something similar mate.

Answer (score 4):

Using video element [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events) "play" and "pause" you can add toggle a class `.playing` to the element, and the rest is simple css, as seen in comments.

```js
video.addEventListener("play", function(ev) {
  ev.target.classList.add("playing");
})


video.addEventListener("pause", function(ev) {
  ev.target.classList.remove("playing");
})
```

```css
#video {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#video:hover {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#video.playing {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#video.playing:hover {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>play/pause/hover</h2>

<video id="video" controls width="250">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

This approach hasn't been tested with all cases (maybe error doesn't fire `pause` etc). But you can take this idea to other methods of detecting video play. according to chatGPT you can:

```js
const videoElement = document.getElementById('myVideo');

function isVideoPlaying() {
  return !videoElement.paused;
}

// Example usage:
if (isVideoPlaying()) {
  console.log('Video is playing!');
} else {
  console.log('Video is paused or not yet started.');
}
```

Comment: That's a really good idea actually, thank you! At the moment I just have screenshot placeholders for the videos but when I have the actual videos, I will give it a go and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript.

I don't know if you can do it with CSS alone.

Look at eventhandlers for entereing the video here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event

And here is a link to some easy to implement code to detect the playingstate of a video

[Detect if video is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877403/how-to-tell-if-a-video-element-is-currently-playing)

Write some javascript that executes on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I just have screenshot placeholders of the videos at the moment but when I have the final videos, I will give it a go and see.