# How do I stop Unslider when playing video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, slider

So, I'm trying out Unslider from http://unslider.com/ because I want a really simple slider, and I love it so far, but I have just one issue:

When I've embedded a Vimeo video using iFrame together with some parameter settings in the URL it show up and plays alright, **but the Unslider won't stop from moving on the the next slide while playing the video.**

I read somewhere that it would work if I added the api=1 parameter at the end of the URL and I tried that but it didn't do anything.

**Worth mentioning is that it stops from moving on to the next slide if you hover over the slider / video**, but I can't assume all of my visitors will do that, so when watching a video I guess they might be quite surprised when the slider suddenly moves on to the next image when the video and sound is still playing in the background.

**Does anyone know how I might fix this?** I'm quite a newbie when it comes to Javascript, but I would love to use Unslider if it could just get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Unslider website and the information is provided as:

```
var slidey = $('.banner').unslider(),
    data = slidey.data('unslider');

//  Start Unslider
data.start();

//  Pause Unslider
data.stop();
```

You can use jQuery to find out if video is clicked or in play mode. [script to check if a video is playing and not restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679184/script-to-check-if-a-video-is-playing-and-not-restart)