# Detect the video-container in a HTML-File

Tags: html, video-streaming, html-parsing

I've got a HTML-file (for example at youtube) and I want to detect the "container" where the video is played in. I don't know if I'm using the right termina. If you need any further explanations, just comment. In that this "container" I hopefully find some meta-information.
Additionally I'd like to know, how to detect if a HTML-page I opened hosts a "container" where a video is played in.

Comment: Do you mean a flash detection (container=plugin) or do you need the <video> element that HTML uses to embed a video inside the page?

Comment: First of all, I would like to get the <video> element. How does that flash detection work? Is it browser-specific?
At least I want to grab metadata from whatever I can get. How can I detect if a html-site plays a video?

Comment: See this answer for the <video>-part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599076/detect-if-html5-video-element-is-playing

Comment: A Flash detection is not browser-specific and can be realised in multiple ways, e.g. via SWFObject. With a Flash detection you'll be able to see if the client supports Flash. However you will hardly be able to extract any metadata from the video itself, since Flash is basically an "alien" object to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for taking time! Well, I knew thats its hardly possible to extract any metadata from the stream itself. Rather I thought I could grab them from a) the html-page itself or b) from another Internet-Site. (Youtube for example provides gdata.youtube.com). But before I can start to grab metadata, I have to know, that theres a video playing.

Comment: Well, as I've written I think for Flash this is almost impossible - you'll be  able to detect an embedded Flash file, but not if it hosts a video. You may be able to check the network traffic to find out if an .mp4 file or any other format is accessed once the site itself is loaded, but thats basically it. In case of HTML5, you can easily search for the <video> tag and go from there.

Comment: I'm already checking the network traffic with a local Proxy I've written. But I don't know how to assign a specific HTTPResponse containing Video-Data with a HTML-Site.
I thought about parsing the HTML-Site, and search it for the video URL. What do you think yout it?