# How to check if my HTML5 video is playing?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a playbutton on my HTML5 video that makes my video play and go into fullscreen mode. This is the code for that:

```
var video = $("#vid");
var playthis = $(".play");
playthis.on('click', function(e){
    var vid = video[0];
    vid.play();
    if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
      vid.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
});
```

What I want to do is to check if my video is playing already, and then hide the play-button. If the video is stopped or paused it should be shown.

Should be easy but it's something that goes wrong.

Comment: video.paused http://stackoverflow.com/q/8599076/2645202

Comment: No clear answers in these posts what I could find.

Comment: if the Play button is hidden, do you still have a Pause/Stop button to change state?