# Is there a way to detect is any video playing on the web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, media, flash

Does anybody know a way to detect is a video playing on a web page or not using javascript. For flash video.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Does "For flash." means "Does anybody know a way to detect if a flash video is playing on a web page or not using javascript ? "

Comment: have a look at this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853904/how-to-detect-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-playing

Comment: I need a way to detect when any flash video is playing using javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if HTML5 Video element is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599076/detect-if-html5-video-element-is-playing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear on what exactly you are trying to do. What do you mean by 'or not using javascript'?

Here are a couple of other questions which may have info to help:

[Detect if HTML5 Video element is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599076/detect-if-html5-video-element-is-playing)

Comment: Sorry, for my bad English. I'm already figured it out for HTML5 video. Now I need javascript solution to detect when a video embeded using flashplayer is playing. Also I need to handle events when user start the video and stop it.