# jQuery: HTML5 audio control floating only when playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am using the following script to with the **audio controls class="box follow-scroll"** to make it float while the page is scrolling.  But I was wondering if it possible to make it float only while the audio is in either ***play*** or ***pause*** mode?  If it stopped it didn't start, it stays where it is.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    (function($) {
        var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
            originalY = element.offset().top;

        var topMargin = 20;
        element.css('position', 'relative');

        $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
            }, 300);
        });
    })(jQuery);

});
```

The html:

```
<audio controls class="box follow-scroll">
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Add event listeners to your audio element. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537318/4746087

Comment: Yes it should work..  but I am not sure how to implement it with the code..  Can you add a reply with the edited script as suggested?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your html and css code?

Comment: Updated the question with the html, and there is no css.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/r4vpt8yk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two eventlisteners to your audio element. One that starts floating when your audio is playing, and one that resets your audio element when it is paused. In the following example the `stopFloating()` resets your audio element by setting `var scrollTop = 0;` to zero. You can of course further tune this function.

Something like:

```
var element = $('.follow-scroll'), originalY = element.offset().top;

var topMargin = 20;
element.css('position', 'relative');

element[0].addEventListener("playing", function() {
    startFloating();
});

element[0].addEventListener("pause", function() {
    stopFloating();
});


function startFloating () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);    
    });
}

// Reset your element
function stopFloating () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

        var scrollTop = 0;

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);    
    });
}
```